# Selenium code to check whether the listbox values are in alphabetical order

Tags: java, selenium

[image]My scenario is to check whether the values in the listbox is in alphabetical order.

My code:

```
package checking;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Alpha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://my.naukri.com/manager/createacc2.php?othersrcp=16201&err=1");

        WebElement single = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ugcourse']"));
        Select dd = new Select(single);
        String str = single.getText();
        System.out.println(str);

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

How to check the values are in alphabetical order. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

### output

```
Select
Not Pursuing Graduation
B.A
B.Arch
BCA
B.B.A
B.Com
B.Ed
BDS
BHM
B.Pharma
B.Sc
B.Tech/B.E.
LLB
MBBS
Diploma
BVSC
Other
```

How to check the values are in alphabetical order. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run over the elements and make sure that each element's value is larger then the previous one.

**UPDATE - PSEUDO CODE**

```
List<WebElement> options = dd.getOptions();
String lastVal = options.get(0).getText();
for (int i=1; i<options.size(); i++) {
    if (options.get(i).getText().compareTo(lastVal) < 0) {
        // assert false, throw some error, whatever you do.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add some example code but I don't understand from your code what is the list. Is it the `option` elements inside the `Select`?

Comment: Itai it says that the second line options[0] is array but we given it as List

Comment: As I said, it is pseudo code. Just replace it with `.get(0)`

Comment: I cannot get the solution. Anyone help me to get solution

Comment: @Vijay I basically wrote the code for you. What's don't you understand? I'll do my best to explain but I think the code is self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry Itai i tried by giving .get(0) but i am getting error

Comment: I have attached the screenshot Itai

Comment: According to your screenshot you haven't changed the `[0]` to `.get(0)`. Please pay more attention to what error and what changes you said you've made before reporting it.

Comment: Thanks Itai and sorry for the mistake. Thanks so much